# How do I stop a selenium script while it's running in python and then start it again from the begining?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver

The issue I'm having is that when I stop the script with driver.close(), I can't start over the script because the instance is tied to the first attempt. Is there a way to start a new instance? I'm using Tkinter to start and stop the selenium script.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.ttk import *
    from SeleniumBot import SeleniumBot
    import threading
    
    root = Tk()
    root.title("SelBot")
    
    # Title of the program
    label = Label(text="SelBot")
    
    text = Text(root, height=5, width=52)
    loadbar = Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')
    s = SeleniumBot()
    
    
    def startBot():
        loadbar.start()
        text.insert(INSERT, 'Bot has started!\n')
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=sBot())
        t1.start()
    
    
    
    def sBot():
        s.login()
        text.insert(INSERT, 'Log In Complete-----------1/3\n')
        s.search()
        text.insert(INSERT, 'Search Complete-----------2/3\n')
        s.complete()
        text.insert(INSERT, 'Task Completed------------3/3\n')
        loadbar.stop()
    
    
    def endBot():
        text.insert(INSERT, 'Bot has stopped!\n')
        s.botStop()
        loadbar.stop()
    
    startBtn = Button(root, text="Start", command=startBot)
    stopBtn = Button(root, text="Stop", command=endBot)
    
    label.pack()
    startBtn.pack()
    stopBtn.pack()
    loadbar.pack()
    text.pack()
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you know that `threading.Thread(target=sBot(s))` should be `threading.Thread(target=sBot, args=(s,))` instead?  The former one will execute `sBot(s)` immediately in *current thread* even without calling `t1.start()`.

Comment: Can you describe why you need to stop the driver running and after that to start it again? What is the logical need / purpose of that?

Comment: If you want to start a new instance, than create the instance of `SeleniumBot()` inside `sBot()` function and make that instance global.

Comment: @acw1668 sorry, I was messing with my code and sBot doesn't take any arguments, but thank you for letting me about that I was unaware.

Comment: @Prophet I feel like it is more intuitive to click a button that says stop in a gui then close the application and start again and click the start button just to start the script over.

Comment: Hm, this is not a commonly used way to run automation. Especially if you think about running it automatically, in headless mode by Jenkinsetc.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with to solve my problem was to put the selenium bot in a list. It's probably not the best solution but it gets the job done for what I want. My reasoning for using a list is that when the stop button is clicked I can stop the selenium bot, then remove it and start a new instance. And when I click the start button it will use the new instance.

```
botList = [SeleniumBot()]


def startBot():
    loadbar.start()
    text.insert(INSERT, 'Bot has started!\n')
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=sBot)
    t1.start()



def sBot():
    botList[0].login()
    text.insert(INSERT, 'Log In Complete-----------1/3\n')
    botList[0].search()
    text.insert(INSERT, 'Search Complete-----------2/3\n')
    botList[0].complete()
    text.insert(INSERT, 'Task Completed------------3/3\n')
    loadbar.stop()


def endBot():
    text.insert(INSERT, 'Bot has stopped!\n')
    botList[0].botStop()
    botList.pop(0)
    botList.append(SeleniumBot())
    loadbar.stop()
```